# .NET Standard vs .NET Framework

Tags: .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.6.2

I'm getting the following error:
`Project .EventPublisher is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Project EventPublisher supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)`

I thought (and accordingly to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/ I'm correct). that 4.6.2 was compatible with .net standard 2.0.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need both? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The project I'm referencing Event Publisher from is .net 4.6.2 and I assumed I'd be able to reference Event Publisher with it being .net standard 2.0....but it seems not

Comment: I just opened VS2017, created a class library in .NET standard 2.0 and a console application in framework 4.6.2 and the console application can reference the library just fine. Maybe you got it mixed up and you tried it the other way round?

Comment: I'm currently thinking it's a build server issue.  We're using the VSTS build hosted pipeline which is failing.  A colleague has pulled the code onto his machine, upgraded his VS 2017 (which was out of date) and it builds for him fine.  So, any ideas what's wrong with the build server that could cause this?  It's using latest VS 2017

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.2 projects can add references to .NET Standard class libraries. The reverse is not supported (yes, that's why you see the failure).

Comment: The problem I was having was with Nuget Restore in VSTS.  I fixed it by changing my .net standard libraries back to .net 4.6.2 ones.  I suspect what has happened is my .net 4.6.2 project was referencing my .net standard 2.0 project which in turn was referencing Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 2.0 which I thought was .NET standard 2.0 but appears to have been trying to import .net framework 4.6.1.  It's odd because it builds fine in VS 2017 locally on my machine (v15.4.5) but not in the shared pipeline in VSTS.  Does this sound like a reasonable explanation or has anyone else got any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using an outdated version of NuGet on your build server. The NuGet Installer step in the build definition should provide an option to specify the NuGet version, or provide a path to the NuGet executable. .NET Standard 2.0 support was added in [NuGet version 4.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-4.3-rtm).